# PHP - MVC, is my aproach correct?

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller

So I have Model, View and Controller, my code works but i have no one to educate me if I do work with it properly.

I won't copy paste the whole code, so therefor I've drawed how it works:

[THE PICTURE: MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzCgI.png)

The part of code:

```
class Site {
protected $config;
 function __construct() {
     $this->config = include("resources/config.php");
 }
 private function connect() { /*database connection*/ }

 public function getData($var) { 
   /* connecting, $var = amout of rows, and storing the data in array() */
}
}

class SiteView {

private $data;

function __construct(Site $data) {
    $this->model = $data;
}
public function output() { 
if(!empty($this->model->data)) { /* displays the data */ }
}
public function render($template) {
   return include("$template");
}
}

class SiteController {
public function __construct(Site $respond) {
    $this->model = $respond;
}

public function condition() {

    $view = new SiteView($this->model);

    $view->render("header.php");

    if(!isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $view->render("body.php");
    } else if($_GET['action'] === "report" AND isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $view->render("report_body.php");
    } else if ...
}
```

So the model and view is used in templates, and I'm not sure if it is a good thing or bad. Thanks for any kind of help or showing me the way.

Comment: I've got at least one feedback: [connecting in the every model you will kill your database server](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#connection).

Comment: I got a variable $db and I'm assigning the connection to it and at the end of each model function that calls for data i have "$this->db = null;" with closes connection, is this alright ?

Comment: No, ist is not all right.

Comment: So i just have to create the connection in __construct {} and assign there the connection to variable ( for me it is "$this->db") then i just can use the variable in other functions? And if i do like in the article i don't need to cover the SQL calls with Try{} and Catch{} ? And everything will work and I'll save the life of my server ? :)

Comment: You should create the connection elsewhere and than pass it in the constructor where assign it to a local variable.Yes, you don't need to cover the SQL calls with Try{} and Catch{} if you are doing it only to report the error.

Comment: Your model is shared between all views, which is fine for a few methods, but could become unwieldy.

Answer (score -2):

The MVC or Model, View and Controller approach is Model is for data which used by user, Controller is the backend logic and View is the output in HTML or the User Interface (UI). 
Normally every request come to the controller first. Controller is connected with the Model and View. Controller collect the data according to the request from Model and send the data to the View for show. View can not able to connect with model.

For more details see this link, [Click Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm)